# htaccess - take all characters after as get request

Tags: php, mysql, regex, .htaccess

The real content is at **domain.com/view.php?id=image_id**

I want to have it be accessible with **domain.com/view/image_id**

The following is currently there to get the `.php` file extensions out.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Appending the following to the htaccess doesn't work:

```
RewriteRule ^view/([A-Za-z0-9]+). /view.php?id=$1 [L, QSA]
```

Also, I am fine with having everything after view.php? (`view.php?id=`) get taken into the php file and from there I can separate everything out by slashes and implement their data.

I have looked at many solutions here on stackoverflow and elsewhere but either they do not apply to me or something is wrong with my server. Either way, I get an `internal 500 server error`. Thanks.

Comment: One other thing of note is that if you plan on further breaking down clean url segment after `/view` in view.php, you might consider going to a full front controller/router pattern and just having logic in index.php to  interpret the first segment in URI (`view` in this case) to determine what controller (`view.php` in this case) that should handle the request.  This will prevent you from having to sprinkle URL interpretation logic throughout a whole bunch of different files.

Comment: Thanks Mike, that would be a wise choice. I am using my own templating framework so I may do that with version 2. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to place the view rule *before* the more general php extension rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^view/([A-Za-z0-9]+)$ /view.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Also, you don't want that space after the `L,`.

Comment: Just about to answer with this comment. The fact the use use `L` flag for the rule means after the rule is executed, the rewrite processing will stop, so if the more specific rule is after the more general rule, it will never be reached.

Answer (score 0):

```
^view/([A-Za-z0-9]+).
                    ^---single character wildcard
```

That `.` at the end there is matching/consuming one of your ID values, so if the url is

```
/view/foobarbaz
```

Your capture group will actually be `foobarba`, and the `z` gets chopped off, producing

```
/view.php?id=foobarba
```

Answer (score 0):

Your 500 Internal Server Error is the result of a redirect loop.

This is because your rule will always be true, because you are redirecting back to the same page.

You need to exclude the resultant link by adding a rule with ^! before all the rest.